# How can we automate content verification for mobile applications (iOS + Android ) without UI automation tools

Tags: android, ios, automation, textview, uitextview

I want to automate the iOS and Android application text (content available on screens), Is there is a generic way or any API available for content verification of mobile application.

I don't want to use any UI automation tools (appium,Calabash).

Answer (score 0):

For Android you could use the Accessibility service to both detect user events and traverse user interfaces. Depending on the permissions you request, you can even alter values and click on behalf of the user.

Check it out here:

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/accessibility/service.html